# Ionic capacitor/cordova blank screen

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

i've got a long issue with ionic. I tried to run through an emulator but all i got is a blank screen. Even with the default tabs app you get with `ionic start`

I've seen few answers talking about the capacitor config file but mine look like this.

```
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'io.ionic.starter',
  appName: 'test-ios',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};

export default config;
```

with `webDir`pointing to `www`like it seems to be good for many people.

Comment: Hi. Does your terminal logs anything?